# What would the notation G/H mean in terms of groups and subgroups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

What would G/H mean in terms of subgroups? Would it most likely mean The compliment group of H in G?

Comment: Isn't this just a quotient group $G/H = \{gH: g \in G\}$? (Sorry, I haven't seen Abstract Algebra in at least two years.)

Comment: @Clarinetist you're close. It is only a group if $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. More generally, it is the set of cosets $\{gH:g\in G\}$. This is inherently confusing notation though since it is quite close to complement notation. There, the slash goes in the opposite direction: $G\backslash H$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams - Just edited the post. Thanks. I always forgot the order I was supposed to multiply them :P

Answer (score 1):

If $H$ is normal in $G$, it means the quotient group. In the more general subgroup case, it could just mean the set of (left) cosets of $H$ in $G$.

Answer (score 0):

If $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, this is the [quotient group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_group): the set of cosets
$$ \{ gH : g \in G \}, $$
equipped with multiplication
$$ g_1 H \cdot g_2 H = (g_1 g_2) H. $$
(Obviously you have to check everything here is well-defined.)